# figlet.setFont() and random.choice() conflicting with each other

Tags: python, cs50, figlet

I'm trying to make figlet text in my terminal in python, as per one of the practice problems in week 6 of CS50. I'm trying to have a font picked randomly from pyfiglet's list of fonts, and I'm trying to implement this as follows:

```
import random
from pyfiglet import Figlet

figlet = Figlet()
figfonts = figlet.getFonts()

# ...

random.seed()
figlet.setFont(random.choice(figfonts)) # error here
```

However, when I run this in my terminal, I get the following error:

`TypeError: Figlet.setFont() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

I'm confused. I'm only providing `figlet.setFont()` 1 argument, why is it saying that there are two? I just can't piece together what the error message is trying to tell me is wrong.

Comment: Every example I can find online of the `.setFont()` method shows the font being specified by a `font=` keyword parameter, rather than a positional parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `setFont` [has the signature](https://github.com/pwaller/pyfiglet/blob/d78b6ab6e05bf39370a134f6847b79e28a937b2e/pyfiglet/__init__.py#L847):

```py
def setFont(self, **kwargs)
```

So passing `font` as a keyword argument (vs. a positional argument like you tried to) should fix the issue (as suggested by [@jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper) in the comments).

For example:

```py
figlet.setFont(font=random.choice(figfonts))
```

---

> I'm confused. I'm only providing `figlet.setFont()` 1 argument, why is it saying that there are two?

As you can see from the signature above, the first positional argument is `self`. Python automatically passes the instance (in this case `figlet`) as the first argument because `setFont` is "bound" to the instance `figlet` when called as `figlet.setFont()`. It's also possible (but unconventional) to call instance methods like so: `Figlet.setFont(figlet)`

Comment: I tried this, but got a different error: `TypeError: Random.choice() got an unexpected keyword argument 'font'`.

Comment: @Mailbox please post the line of code that's causing the error.

Comment: Excuse me. In the original code I posted, I replaced `figlet.setFont(random.choice(figfonts))` with `figlet.setFont(font=random.choice(figfonts))`.

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you sure you're not doing this? `figlet.setFont(random.choice(font=figfonts))`

Comment: Lmao, that's exactly the mistake I made. I fixed it and it works now, thank you! How did you predict that mistake?